# Prototyping for UX: dev plan + jQuery / Framework?

Tags: javascript, css, frameworks

I started to work as a UX designer and until recently have been prototyping using visual tools like Axure or Balsamiq mockups.I've always been drawn to coding though and want to become more code-oriented in my prototyping skills.
I'd like to know your opinion on choosing the right development path in my particular situation. Briefly:

### What I know:

HTML + CSS, Bootstrap 4 basics, basic coding concepts (like variables, functions, classes etc.) I recently started to learn vanilla JS basic concepts.

### What I want to be able to do

- rapidly prototype (in order of importance!) 1. apps(!), 2. dashboards(!), 3. mobile apps, 4. web sites
- have intermediate understanding of code and ability to modify it
- create dynamic, animated graphs (d3.js?)
- (important) dynamic animations of UI elements

### Goals:

- First of all I want to plan my coding schedule for next 4-5 years in advance. I understand there is no best tool and perfect path, that's why I want to follow "good enough" path.
- I don't necessarily look for the newest and shiniest technology. For my purposes it needs to be efficient today and shouldn't die in a few years.

### Questions:

- I think it's a good idea to keep learning JS to say intermediate point,until I'll get into frameworks/libraries. **That's the usual advice**, but on the other hand, I only need code as far as prototyping is concerned, maybe results would come faster if I skip to frameworks directly?
- If my goal is just prototyping is it still bad idea to learn jQuery afterwards? I see a lot of bad reviews recently. Should I consider (and why) any other frameworks/libs like React? In other words are there any advantages of say React over jQuery **for my purposes**?
- Can I still use css frameworks with JS Frameworks? The concept of latter is to complicated for my now and I wonder if they can be useful for prototyping purposes or it's just a tool for professional developers (so many options, so many tools!).

Thanks!

Comment: What is the goal of being more code-oriented ? Do you want to have a usable code that can be used by the developer ? Or do you only want to have the visual prototype no matter if the code behind is ugly and not usable ?

Comment: I'd like my code to be more usable for developer, with proper modifications of course. I also think coding is just extremely useful skill and I plan to keep coding in the future (I plan to learn python for data manipulation).

Comment: Then it will depend on the technology used for the project. If a web app is using AngularJS but you come with a prototype using ReactJS, it will be complicated to integrate it. Same about HTML+CSS, some app (smartphone) do not use HTML or CSS. By the way, I am not a designer. I am a developer but I don't work with designer thus I don't know how they work together. You should maybe post your question on **graphic design**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it's a good idea to keep learning JS to say intermediate
>   point,until I'll get into frameworks/libraries. That's the usual
>   advice, but on the other hand, I only need code as far as prototyping
>   is concerned, maybe results would come faster if I skip to frameworks
>   directly?

Often frameworks have a clear documentation of their functions and methods and therefore I think jumping into a framework directly would spare some time. On parallel learning JS is quite important in order to recognize JS formats and modify your requirements. I would just focus on a framework with a specific goal. Try to implement it and if you encounter some errors just google it, you will definitely find some stack overflow questions.

> If my goal is just prototyping is it still bad idea to learn jQuery
>   afterwards? I see a lot of bad reviews recently. Should I consider
>   (and why) any other frameworks/libs like React? In other words are
>   there any advantages of say React over jQuery for my purposes?

It is never bad to learn jQuery. A lot of external libraries are build based on jQuery. I would really recommend this book: "[Jon Duckett-
JavaScript & JQuery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118531647)" which will help you understand the basics of jQuery. I do not see any advantages of React over jQuery. Perhaps some other people have different thoughts about that.

> Can I still use css frameworks with JS Frameworks? The concept of
>   latter is to complicated for my now and I wonder if they can be useful
>   for prototyping purposes or it's just a tool for professional
>   developers (so many options, so many tools!).

Sure, JS Frameworks often only focus on creating dynamic content or establishing functionality within your prototype. It does not really influence your CSS. You can easily use for example node.js in combination with bootstrap CSS .

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look up the book you recommend. Regarding jQuery, I'm still a bit concerned it's (sort of) dying technology, are there any real alternatives with similar learning curve with potentially longer life span?

Comment: Why do you think jQuery is a dying technology? Were did you read that? It is still heavily under development and used by around: 67,884,357 websites (see: [buildwith](https://trends.builtwith.com/javascript))

Comment: I hope it's not, but looking at developers opinions and trends, just wonder will it still be here in a few years, just when I may reach a certain degree of proficiency in it  :) https://www.dropbox.com/s/9th9efbknm5g73e/trends.png?dl=0

Comment: Your are looking at the trends of stackoverflow questions. You can also look it at the other way around: less stackoveflow questions might mean that there are less bugs / feature requirements. Which means that jQuery might be so stable that it can provide the needs of their users. The learning curve will always be taken into account. jQuery can not stop their development due to the fact that is supports a large amount of websites. For each new feature jQuery often also creates extensions like: jQuery UI, jQuery mobile etc,.

Comment: That's an interesting point, I will do more research on jQ and probably try to go in this direction. Thank you ALL ^ for your time!

Comment: @KrisZap No problem and keep in mind I am not saying that jQuery is the only way to go. There are other libraries as well. It depends on the need of your application. You do not want to use a library which is not heavily developed and supported so that in the feature you might end up with compatibility problems ;)